# Помогите написать цикл, который заполнит переменную значениями. Решите задачу

Tags: python

**Задача**

В предыдущем задании вы написали цикл, который вывел на экран заработок «Лютиков и других цветочков» от продаж платной версии приложения за каждый месяц. Теперь напишите цикл, который сохранит эти данные в отдельный список — monthly_income.

**Подсказка:**

Объявите переменную monthly_income и сохраните в ней пустой список. Затем напишите цикл, который пройдёт по всем элементам payers и добавит в список monthly_income результат умножения каждого элемента на purchase_amount, применяя метод append().

**Мои потуги новичка - Код:**

```py
payers = [75, 48, 65, 68, 74, 67, 71, 65, 90, 85, 79, 81]
purchase_amount = 5  # сумма покупки в долларах
monthly_income = [] # создайте список monthly_income
for monthly_income in payers:
    monthly_income.append(*purchase_amount)  # напишите цикл, который заполнит monthly_income значениями
print(monthly_income) # выводим новый список на экран
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что в `for` цикле переопределяется название вашего пустого списка `monthly_income`. Чтобы исправить я ввел переменную `payer`, которая каждую итерацию будет хранить одно значение из списка `payers`, которое и будет умножаться на значение `purchase_amount`

```py
payers = [75, 48, 65, 68, 74, 67, 71, 65, 90, 85, 79, 81]
purchase_amount = 5  
monthly_income = [] 

for payer in payers:    
    monthly_income.append(payer * purchase_amount) 

print(monthly_income)
```

Comment: Благодарочка, за столь быстрый корректный ответ, - это очень помогло мне!

Comment: @VadimNaumov на здоровье, не забывайте оценивать ответы и отмечать принятыми, те которые решают вашу проблему и соответствуют вашим ожиданиям

Comment: "...не забывайте оценивать ответы и отмечать принятыми, те которые решают вашу проблему и соответствуют вашим ожиданиям..." - а где узнать как это делать? Всё разобрался)

Comment: @VadimNaumov вот здесь можете найти инфу - [что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Вроде так

```
payers = [75, 48, 65, 68, 74, 67, 71, 65, 90, 85, 79, 81]
purchase_amount = 5  
monthly_income = [] 

for i in payers:
    monthly_income.append(i * purchase_amount)
print(monthly_income)
```